# How to have a Python Django map with a satellite view using from django.contrib.gis.db import models?

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I know python and I know a bit of Django. Lately I have been trying to upgrade my maps that I use in my app to a satellite view.
Right on my map I am able to draw multiple polygons and save it to the database (postGres).

I am using the following to draw the map:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
myMap = models.MultiPolygonField(verbose_name="Boundaries Map", null=True, blank=True, srid=4326)
```

The only thing I wanted to do is instead of having the map View have a Satellite view.
Does anyone know any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of search I found this Solution: Check this tutorial http://mattmakesmaps.com/blog/2013/05/01/django-add-mapquest-tiles/

So this is the foundation for what I had to do, after that you need to find tiles for your map that actually work. I opted to use ESRI map tiles.

Comment: The image tile server for Django released by Kitware might serve the purpose very well.  Three resources: https://youtube.com/watch?v=v3e2ODCK9Co&t=31247s ; https://github.com/girder/django-large-image ;  https://www.kitware.com/dynamic-tile-serving-built-in-to-your-django-projects/